# How to endjob RGZPFM in AS400

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange, rpgle, clp

I tried to run the Reorganize Physical File (RGZPFM) on one of the files. I executed it through a submitted job running in QBATCH. Due to it taking too long, I eventually decided to end the job immediately, but the job didn't terminate. Is there a solution for such a situation?"

here my setup when first i'm running the job

[my parameter when i'm running (RGZPFM)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8E39.png)

i try terminate the job but still failed
[my parameter when i try to terminate the job](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h47BM.png)

here picture job still running its already 20 days
[pic job still running after 20 days](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSxko.png)

Answer (score 3):

I did a search in https://www.ibm.com/mysupport/ for

> RGZPFM LOOP

("LOOP" is the keyword that IBM adds to the keyword-string for this type of problem)

The search found this APAR https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/apar/SE80240 which has PTFs for 7.4 and 7.5.

> **OSP-DB-OTHER-LOOP RGZPFM LOOP CAN NOT END**
>
> **Problem Summary**
>
> The Reorganize Physical File Member (RGZPFM) command with the
> ALWCANCEL(*YES) option takes a long time to end after being
> canceled.
>
> **Problem Conclusion**
>
> The operation would do extraneous processing when handling a
> cancel request which could take a long period of time. This
> processing will be avoided when canceling.

It doesn't indicate whether the PTF will help with an existing RGZPFM that won't end, but I'm guessing that it would only affect new RGZPFM ...

The text of the APAR suggests that it will take "a long time"; it doesn't say that it will never end, so maybe it just needs more days, although 20 days is a VERY long time.

I would contact IBM to see if it is safe to use the ENDJOBABN command for that job.

Comment: I have not contacted IBM yet, but I took a risk and performed ENDJOBABN as per the information you provided, and it worked. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: Yes, RGZPFM is potentially dangerous to cancel. Basically, it pushes all data together in a PF. There is a good reason why the system won't let you cancel it. You could end up with duplicate records if you force it, a problem that might show up only years later in the application. Old-school would recommend a SAVE of the file first for safety.